# if line contains an element in list

Tags: python-2.7

trying to analyse a text file

```
file = open('alert.ids',"r")
for line in file:
```

in order to do this, I have a list which contains keywords

keyWordList = ["Consecutive TCP small segments exceeding threshold","TCP 
session without 3-way handshake"]

my text file is divided into paragraphs, some of them contains one of these two keywords 
what is the best way to do this

Comment: What do you have tried? please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @JorgeHortelano   i tried to write it like this
keyWordList = ["[**] [129:12:1] Consecutive TCP small segments exceeding threshold [**]","Consecutive TCP small segments exceeding threshold","TCP session without 3-way handshake"]

file = open("aladdin.ids","r")
for line in file:
    if (s for s in keyWordList if line in s):
        print "True"
    else:
        print "no"
    
but for each line in the text i get true

Comment: @Psytho  actually im working on a SEIM project, and im trying to write a parser that analysis a text file, and according to the info in this file i can decide what kind of attack is this, so i need to have a list of keywords that helps me decide which attack is this